# Como pasar variables a Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hola soy nuevo en `c#` y necesito pasar en la siguiente `función(PostFailure)` en `js` una variable string de `c#`. El problema es que el parámetro `message` tiene un `json` que no logro entender de dónde llega. Mi código actual es:

Index.cshtml

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new AjaxOptions {
HttpMethod = "post", OnBegin = "PostOnBegin", OnFailure =
"PostFailure", OnSuccess = "PostSuccess", OnComplete =
"PostOnComplete" })) {...
```

anylib.js

```
function PostFailure(message){

}
```

La idea sería:

Index.cshtml

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new AjaxOptions {
HttpMethod = "post", OnBegin = "PostOnBegin", OnFailure =
"PostFailure(messaje,'hola')", OnSuccess = "PostSuccess", OnComplete = 
"PostOnComplete" }))
```

anylib.js

```
function PostFailure(message,x){

}
```

pero me salta error de compilación.

Comment: pero la variable "mensaje" que defines en el OnFailure de donde la estas tomando ?

Comment: Ese es el problema que cuando ejecuto el código dentro de la variable message hay un json que no se de donde viene. Puede ser alguna herencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sería mas simple si usas

```
function PostFilure(){
   var  x= 'hola';
   var mensaje = $('#control').val();

}
```

o sea obtienes el valor de forma dinamica del control que tiene ese dato

Si es algo contextual podrias definir

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "post", OnBegin = "PostOnBegin", OnFailure = "PostFailure", OnSuccess = "PostSuccess", OnComplete = "PostOnComplete" })) {

    @Html.Hidden(x=> x.Prop);

    <!--resto html-->
}
```

con un hidden y tomarlo desde allí usando

```
var mensaje = $('#hiddenId').val();
```

Donde apunto es que los parametros los asignes a hidden dentro del contexto del `Ajax.BeginForm` para tomarlo por `jquery` en lugar de pasarlo por parametro.

Comment: mas que un valor necesito pasar una variable string de c# hacia anylib.js> function PostFilure(){}

Comment: Pero para pasarla desde c# entonces el action deberias enviar ese dato en el model de la view, es por eso que mencione el Html.Hidden() es alli donde la asignas y la tomas desde anylib.js

Comment: Sabes de donde pueden llegar los datos message?

Comment: no entendi la pregunta, como es eso de donde pueden llegar? si es desde c# vendrian en el model de la view desde el action